# get values from php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    ['source'] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Amharic
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Azerbaijani
                )

        )

    ['target'] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Assamese
                    [1] => Bengali
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bhojpuri
                    [1] => Gujarati
                )

        )
```

As you can see the values are getting in array and those are in two sets. One is in source and other is in target.
So for source[0] is for the value of target is target[0]..and it goes like this
. So for the souI want to get the values in dropdown. so from this array the value should come like this

```
<div class="test">
    <select name="source" id="">
        <option value="Amharic">Amharic</option>
    </select>

    <select name="target" id="">
        <option value="Assamese">Assamese</option>
        <option value="Bengali">Bengali</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <select name="source" id="">
        <option value="Azerbaijani">Azerbaijani</option>
    </select>

    <select name="target" id="">
        <option value="Bhojpuri">Bhojpuri</option>
        <option value="Gujarati">Gujarati</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

To get values I am using my code like this

```
<?php foreach($language_datas as $language_data) {
                        foreach ($language_data as $lang_data) {
                            print_r($lang_data);
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

This one is getting result like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Amharic
)
Array
(
    [0] => Azerbaijani
)
Array
(
    [0] => Assamese
    [1] => Bengali
)
Array
(
    [0] => Bhojpuri
    [1] => Gujarati
)   

)
```

So can someone kindly tell me how to get the values as like referenced. Any help and suggestions will be really appreceable,

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

```
<?php foreach($language_datas['source'] as $k=>$data) {
    echo '<div class="test">';
    echo '<select name="source" id="">';
        foreach($data as $point){
            echo '<option value="' . $point . '">' . $point . '</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';

    echo '<select name="target" id="">';
        foreach($language_datas['target'][$k] as $point){
            echo '<option value="' . $point . '">' . $point . '</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
} ?>
```

Although this assumes that you will always have the correct array structure which might not be the best method to do things, but it solves your issue.

Comment: It is showing `Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`
The arrays are generating dynamically...

Comment: How are your arrays being generated exactly? The more information you provide the better we can help. Your question is slightly confusing =/

Comment: actually I am getting the array after unserialize data.

Comment: Considering you're getting an error of 'invalid argument' for both mine and peepbo's code I'm assuming something is wrong with the code you've provided.... Can you potentially let us know the exact serialized string as well as what variable it's being put into? I'm not seeing the 'invalid' argument when using the data you've provided...

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question. So you want to get all targets corresponding to the source with the same key?

In this case, try following code:

```
foreach ($language_datas['source'] as $key => $source) {
    print_r($source); // Show the source array
    print_r($language_data['target'][$key]); // Show the corresponding target array
}
```

Depending on how your array is created, you should also check if `$language_data['target'][$key]` exists before accessing (`isset($language_data['target'][$key])`).

Comment: it is showing `Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: There was a typo (language_data instead of datas). Please try again.